# Set Laravel session lifetime in controller

Tags: laravel, session, model-view-controller, laravel-5.6

I know how to change session lifetime and expire_on_close in (config/seasion.php file) but I want to set lifetime and expire_on_close in controller, Because I want to detemine those on demand.

I searched in Laravel documentation but I didn't find any useful guide.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/configuration#accessing-configuration-values),

> To set configuration values at runtime, pass an array to the config helper:

`config(['session.lifetime' => 30]);`

---

Tested in artisan tinker:

```
>>> Config::get('session.lifetime');
=> 120
>>> config(['session.lifetime' => 30]);
=> null
>>> Config::get('session.lifetime');
=> 30
```

Comment: I put `config(['session.lifetime' => 30]);` in a method in my controller that execute in program but it didn't change anything and lifetime is 120 yet

Comment: Which method did you out in??

Comment: A custom function